# How can I edit or remove the bounding box label text in YOLO (V4)?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, bounding-box, yolov4

I want to edit the bounding box label to **show only the probability of detection and not the class label**, How shall I do this?

I found a file called `image.c` in darknet/src which I think is where my edits need to be made.
But there are multiple functions in it that seem relevant for this task and I'm not sure which one to edit, and how to edit to get what I want. The code in `image.c` in quite long, hence kindly refer to [this](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/image.c) link (official darknet repo) where the code I'm referring to is available.

I tried editing the function `void draw_detections` at line 465 by simply changing the code at line 511 to `printf("%s: %.0f%%", " ", prob * 100);`, ran the `!make` command but the labels were still present in detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found how to do this:

Locate the file `darknet/src/image.c`

**Delete** lines of code at 436

```
strcat(labelstr, names[selected_detections[i].best_class]);
```

and from line 441 to 446

```
for (j = 0; j < classes; ++j) { 
    if (selected_detections[i].det.prob[j] > thresh && j != selected_detections[i].best_class) { 
        strcat(labelstr, ", "); 
        strcat(labelstr, names[j]); 
    } 
}
```

Make sure to rebuild the darknet in the project (`!make`)

*Note:These changes will erase out if the darknet repository is cloned again.*

Comment: If you want to actually change the labels (to another language for example) you can edit the file `darknet/data/coco.names`

Answer (score 0):

You are using alexyAB model in your project .go to the image_opencv.cpp file and find draw_detections_cv_v3 function after that find this line:

```
 strcat(labelstr, names[j]);
```

change to:

```
strcat(labelstr, "");
```

Comment: Made the suggested changes inside the function, ran the !make command, but still showing the class labels. This didn't do anything. (There are two lines of 'strcat(labelstr, names[j]);' in the given function, I changed both)